# Spliting and sum of chars

Tags: java, algorithm, char, integer

I have to write a function that finds the smallest number where the sum of its digits its N. I couldn't figure it out in a better way that brute force, but its not adding properly, when adding the ints on the array, it sums on a really weird pattern.

```
public int sumN(int N) {
        int total = 10;
        char[] n;
        ArrayList<Integer> nrs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int sum = 0;
        String x = "";
        if(N<=9)
            return N;
        else
        {
            while(true)
            {   
                x = Integer.toString(total);
                n = x.toCharArray();
                for(char c : n)
                {
                    nrs.add(Character.getNumericValue(c));
                }
                for(Integer i : nrs)
                {
                    sum = sum + i;
                }
                if(sum == N)
                {
                    return total;
                }
                total++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: *"I couldn't figure it out in a better way that brute force, but even so, my math seems a bit off."* But what specifically is your question?

Comment: Sorry, i edited the question with a bit more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title and description are a bit at odds so I may have misunderstood the question, but was fun to work on in any event.

But I think your asking for an algorithm to produce the smallest valued number whose base-10 digits add up to N.  (Question better suited for a Math exchange maybe.)

One assumption:

```
N > 0
```

A few observations are made:

1. The largest value of any single base-10 digit is 9.
2. The largest N that can be obtained with w digits is `Math.pow(10,w) - 1`.  (For example if w is 2 digits then the largest number is (10**2)-1 or 99.
3. The minimum number of digits x for a number to add to N must be ceil(N/9).  (For example for an N=20 the value must have at least 3 digits since the largest value of the sum of 2 digits is 18=9+9.)

So the problem is reduced to minimizing the most significant digit since that would represent the lowest possible number irrespective of the lesser digits.

So to minimize the most significant digit one should maximize the remaining digits which is (x-1) 9's.

So assuming x is calculated as the minimum number of digits:

```
x = ceil(N/9)               // e.g. N=82, x=10
```

then the least significant digits are a series of (x-1) 9's:

```
y = pow(10,(x-1))-1         // 999999999
```

so minimizing the most significant digit becomes

```
z = ((N - (9 * (x-1))) * pow(10,(x-1))   // 1000000000
```

and then the result is

```
r = (z + y)                // 1999999999
```

So how does one prove it is the least possible number whose digits sum to N?

Note the numbers get big quickly so if you need to handle any value for N you need to use `BigInteger` which handles arbitrary precision.

---

Here's an attempt at proof:

Assume there exists an `m` whose value is less than `r` (above):

```
m < r
```

Assume that m has fewer digits than r which by definition would satisfy the condition.

But if

```
SUM(digits of m) == SUM(digits of r) == N
```

and r has a '9' for every digit that m has (all 9's except most significant digit) and r has one extra digit, there is no `m` which could be fewer digits and satisfy above condition.

Assume `m` has the same number of digits and is less than `r`.  In this case to be less than `r` the most significant digit of `m` must be less than the most significant digit of `r`.  Since the remaining digits (if any) of `r` are 9's, there are no possible remaining digits for 'm' which could amount to a number to make up the difference in the most significant digits so `m` cannot be the same number of digits and have a most significant digit less than `r`.

If `m` has the same number of digits but the most significant digit is greater than `r` then by definition is a larger number.

If `m` has more digits than `r` then by definition is a larger number.